# Radio button value in php not showing

Tags: php, html

I have a form that searches my local database. Its still in its production phase. However when I try to get the value of my radio button there is nothing. Below is the code:

## PHP

```php
$k = $_GET['k'];
$terms = explode(" ", $k);
$query = "SELECT * FROM  series8000 WHERE ";
$vision = $_GET['Vision'];
$new = $_GET['new1'];
$sithelo = sithelo;
foreach ($terms as $each) {
    $i++;
    if ($i == 1)
        $query .= "Description LIKE '%$each%' ";
    else
        $query .= "OR Description LIKE '%$each%' ";
}   
$query .= "AND VisionType = '$vision' ";

if (!empty($new1 )) {
    $query .= "AND Change = '$new1' ";
}
```

## HTML

```html
<form action='index.php' method='get'>
<fieldset>


                <legend>Change</legend> 


                    <label for="New" class="property">New Product</label>
                    <div class="labels">
                        <input type="radio"  name="new1" <?php if (isset($new1) && $new1 == "N") echo "checked=yes"; ?>size="30" value="N"/>
                        <input type="radio"  name="new1" size="30" value="Y"/>
                        <input type="radio"  name="new1" size="30"  value="YN"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    </div>  

                    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

The challenge is the value of the radio button with name new1 comes blank when I echo in my php code not shown here. I have to get the value of the radio button so that i can use it in my query.

Comment: This is a huge amount of (badly formatted) code, which is difficult to read and would take a long time to try and work out. Please reduce the code to only the relevant areas, and format it so more readable.

Comment: You really need to go and relearn how to use the `<label>` element. Each label is for *one* form control (so you need one per radio, not one per radio group) and the `for` attribute refers to an `id` not a `name`.

Comment: @freefaller I have formatted the code.

Comment: @Quentin Thanks Quentin. i am still a novice and would appreciate how to handle the value of the radio button in php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put the value of new1 in a variable $new but you don't seem to use it when it comes to this line:

```
if (!empty($new1 )) {
    $query .= "AND Change = '$new1' ";
}
```

Try perhaps with:

```
if (!empty($new)) {
    $query .= "AND Change = '$new' ";
}
```

And also use what Kalai said:

```
 echo "checked='checked'";
```

Answer (score 3):

Please try with `checked= 'checked'` instead of using checked=yes.

Comment: Still giving me a blank value for the radio button.

Comment: Have got that radio button is checked

Comment: Somewhere in my code I have echo "Found $new1 records"; This comes out as Found records. I have made the changes to <?php if (isset($new1) && $new1 == "N") echo "checked = 'checked'"; ?>. This just keeps the radio button checked when selected on page reload.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```html
<input type="radio"  name="new1" <?php if (isset($new1) && $new1 == "N") echo "checked=yes"; ?>size="30" value="N"/>
```

Into

```html
<input type='radio' name='new1' <?php if (isset($new1) && $new1 == "N") echo "checked='checked' "; ?>size='30' value='N'/>
```

My answer differs since *there is a lack of space* between the outputted `checked='checked'` and the `size='30'` in previous answers.